# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException on API Call

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Trying to understand a piece of code that fails to add a new row to a DB. It's the registration of a company that makes an API call to:

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public Company register(@Valid @RequestBody UserRegistrationModel newCompany, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    Category cat = this.catRepo.findByName("Andere");
    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return this.createCompany(newCompany).get();
    } else {
        // throw fancy error!
        throw new InvalidRequestException("There were binding errors!", null);
    }
}
```

The `POST` fails with the following statement:

```
{timestamp: 1541400035590, status: 500, error: "Internal Server Error",…}

error: "Internal Server Error"

exception: "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException"

message: "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"

path: "/api/companies/register"

status: 500

timestamp: 1541400035590
```

Where should I look first? DB constraints?

Comment: seems you can't add Company info without adding entries in dependent table. Yes, you need to check DB constraint that company table has.

Comment: Could be any type of db constraint. Would need the stack trace, the annotations on UserRegistrationModel and possibly the constraints defined in on the table if not annotated on the java entity.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the ID can you post yoru POJO and their Mapping please